# Error Propagation on Orbital Elements through Non Linear Relation

Tags: matrices, physics, nonlinear-system, error-propagation

I'm having a hard time trying to propagate errors for my current work. I have two known positions $X$ and $Y$ that depend on several orbital parameters $r,  i, \Omega, \omega, f$  ($r$ is a distance and $i, \Omega, \omega, f$ are angles).

I know the errors $\Delta X$, $\Delta Y$ associated to the positions $X$ and $Y$ and I'd like to determine the errors associated to the other parameters $r,  i, \Omega, \omega, f$ except that the relation between them is non linear.

$X$ and $Y$ can be written as follows :

\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos{\Omega} & -\sin{\Omega} \\
    \sin{\Omega} & \cos{\Omega} \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & \cos{i} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos{\omega} & -\sin{\omega} \\
    \sin{\omega} & \cos{\omega} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix} r\cos f \\ r\sin f \end{pmatrix} \\ \\\\
\end{equation}

which also writes :

\begin{equation}
    \begin{matrix}
    X = r (\cos\Omega\cos(\omega +f)-\sin(\Omega)\sin(\omega +f)\cos{i}) \\
    Y = r (\sin\Omega\cos(\omega +f)+\cos(\Omega)\sin(\omega +f)\cos{i})
    \end{matrix}
\end{equation}

As $X$ and $Y$ are not correlated, I've tried to determine the error with this equation :

\begin{equation}
    \sigma^2_{\mu} \approx \left| \frac{\partial f_{\mu}}{\partial X}\right| ^2\sigma^2_X+\left| \frac{\partial f_{\mu}}{\partial Y}\right|^2\sigma^2_Y
\end{equation}

where $\mu$ is one of my orbital parameters. But for that, I have to establish for each of them the function $f_{\mu}$ that depends on $X$ and $Y$.

I tried with $i$ for example but it looks odd... here is what I have for the moment :

\begin{equation}
\cos i\Bigg|_{\omega+f \ne 0} = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \dfrac{X+Y - r\cos(\omega +f) \left( \cos\Omega+\sin\Omega \right)}{r\sin(\omega + f)(\cos\Omega-\sin\Omega)} & \mbox{if } \Omega \ne \dfrac{\pi}{4}(4k+1) \mbox{, } k \in \mathbb{Z} \\
        & \\
        \dfrac{Y-X}{2 r \cos\Omega \sin(\omega+f)} &  \mbox{ else.}
    \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f_{i}(X,Y) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \arccos\left( \dfrac{X+Y - r\cos(\omega +f) \left( \cos\Omega+\sin\Omega \right)}{r\sin(\omega + f)(\cos\Omega-\sin\Omega)} \right) & \mbox{if } \Omega \ne \dfrac{\pi}{4}(4k+1) \mbox{, } k \in \mathbb{Z} \\
        & \\
        \arccos\left(  \dfrac{Y-X}{2 r \cos\Omega \sin(\omega+f)} \right) &  \mbox{ else.}
    \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

But near $\Omega=\pi/4$ and $\Omega=5\pi/4$, my expression of $\cos i$ explodes and the arccos function is only defined between $[-1,1]$ so I'm not sure if this is the right way to propagate the errors. Plus, establishing a differentiable function that depends on $X$ and $Y$ will not be possible for all of my orbital parameters. So I'd like to know if there is another way, especially with the matrice formulation of the problem, I searched for a while but nothing seems to really answer my problem...

Thank you very much to those who'll answer, and have a nice day !

Comment: As a non-analytical kludge, you might try simulating the result: Generate samples of $X,Y$ according to a hand-selected distribution, and observe the resulting distribution on $\cos i$.

Comment: Ok I see...And there is no way to compute the errors more cleanly ?

Comment: I'm not saying there isn't, but that this may be a cheaper and less algebra-intensive alternative. (If you want to see what an algorithm does, you could look at its internals and track what it's doing step-by-step...or you can feed in typical inputs to find out what the typical outputs are.)